# Bootstrap navbar with progressive collapse nav

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation, progressive

My navigation contains many list items so I was trying to find a solution to hide the extra items automatically. I found [this solution](http://bootbites.com/articles/freebie-bootstrap-navbar-progressive-collapse-nav) online, but my navigation goes into two line anyway. Maybe I am not using it properly.

Has anyone ever used it before and know how to solve my issue?